# bootstrap multi step form validation with insert update in database via js ajax

Tags: validation, ajaxform, multi-step

I'm stuck in multiple step form with 10pages on landing page to validate and input text should insert and update in database without submit
once user fill any value in input then that value insert in database otherwise update
thanks in advance